# Special Acronym Finder

Tags: ms-word, acronym

I'm compiling an acronyms/abbreviations table for a document. Beyond a simple acronym finder, I would like to find special acronyms that aren't entirely conventional.

Generally I can find acronyms by using `<[A-Z]{2,}>` in an advanced search. This captures any whole word that is comprised solely of uppercase letters. But I have acronyms that take on other forms too. Beyond an acronym being in the form `ABC` I have acronyms in this document of other forms.

1. `ABC` Generic form, 2 or more uppercase letters
2. `AB&C` 1 or more letters preceding and following `&`
3. `ABC(D)` 1 letter in parentheses following 2 or more letters (this only appears twice, so I'm not too worried about it.)
4. `A/C` 1 or more letters both preceding and following `/`
5. `ABC-12` 2 or more letters followed by a hyphen and 1 or 2 numbers. This only appears once, so I'm not really worried about it.

In my efforts to create an acronym finder, I've developed this specialized search.

`<[A-Z]{1,}[\&\/]*[A-Z]{1,}>`

Trying to translate this, I see that this is searching for 1 or more uppercase letters preceding 0 or more of `&` or `/` followed by 1 or more uppercase letters. In theory this should find forms 1,2, and 4, but in reality it only finds forms 2 and 4, and not 1. (I'm not as much worried about form 3 as I am form 1, 2, and 4.) I'm stumped at what I need to change. I've tried doing an `OR |` statement to find one or more form, but Microsoft Word's 'regex' options are different (or appear to be different) from what I generally use.

In summary, my question is what form should my special acronym finder be to find forms 1, 2, and 4 in the table above?

Comment: «This is not possible because MSWord lacks ...» Wrong. See my answer.

Comment: The OP makes no mention of false positives... What the OP did say is that he/she is trying to find unconventional acronyms as well as the normal kind.

Comment: @macropod Can Confirm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *wildcard* Find, where:

Find = <[A-Z][A-Z0-9&()/-]{1,}

Beyond that, for identifying acronyms in parentheses and the text to which they refer, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/42313-acronym-definiton-list-generator.html

See also: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/19395-acronym-finder-macro-microsoft-word.html

Comment: I used a slightly modified version of your wildcard find above, `<[A-Z][A-Z\&\/\-]{1,}>` and this finds everything I'm looking for. It does find some acronyms 'twice' but that's not an issue. i.e. It finds AB/CD and CD within that. But again, that doesn't matter as long as it found the whole!

Comment: OK, but that won't find acronyms like ABC-12. If used in a macro, collapsing the found range to its end after each find would avoid the 'AB/CD and CD within that' scenario.

Comment: I mentioned in my post I'm not really worried about the ABC-12 form, as it only appears once in a 500+ page document. Hence my edit to your suggestion.